# Plot of a big number of segment in python (using matplotlib or pyqtgraph)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, pyqtgraph

I have a program that generates around n = 100 000 segments, that I decided to store inside an array of shape (n,2,2) (where a segment is coded by the two points making its extremities). My plot is in **2D**.

I've been trying to plot those segments with for n = 10 000 (that is way lower than I want) and it took around an hour to run and to appear on my screen. I do not have a really powerful computer (RAM: 8gb ; and a core i5 that is neither really powerful nor recent) but I hope that I can make things faster. The method I used was to go through my (n,2,2)-NumPy-array and plot a line between each pair of two points using matplotlib.

What I want:

1) Being able to draw those segments in static at first

2) Making things interactive (I want to see the projection of the set of those segments one axis line and then rotate my set to see how the projections changes)

---

EDIT: so I almost found out a way: plotting with pyqtgraph.
If I say "almost" that's because this is super fast when I plot every segment in one line, using the following code:

```
plotWidget = pg.plot(title="Test")

X = []
Y = []

for u in A:
    X.append(u[0,0])
    X.append(u[1,0])
    Y.append(u[0,1])
    Y.append(u[1,1])
plotWidget.plot(X,Y, pen='g')
```

Where A is a numpy array of shape (n,2,2). When I lunch it with n= 10 000 it takes less than one second to plot. However, it plots everything in one line and I want to plot it segment by segment.

So I tried the following code:

```
for u in A:
    plotWidget.plot([u[0,0],u[1,0]],[u[0,1],u[1,1]],pen = 'g')
```

But after an hour, it didn't show up... I think it's because the call of "plot" is heavy (that's also maybe the problem with what I did with matplotlib).

I will try to use Vispy to see whether it works better for my case.

---

EDIT2: I discovered the collection in matplotlib. I used "Linecolletion" and now can plot really fast using matplotlib!

However, **I would like to do the same with pyqtgraph.** How to do so?

Comment: 1) Would it work for you to just plot the projection? It seems easy to quickly calculate that in numpy, and then plot it dynamically. 2) Overall, with this type of problem where you're trying to plot much more than your visual system could even take in, it will probably be more effective to try to think of a different representation of the data, for the benefit of both you and your overburdened computer.

Comment: @tom10 1) Yes it is. However, it seems to be the same problem since I want to calculate the projection of all the segments, that will give the same number of segments but onto only one line. 2) What would you suggest?

Comment: 1) Calculating the projected distribution will be much much faster than plotting all of the lines. If that would work for you, could you write a few sentences on exactly what you want for the projection, and show what you've tried. 2) It entirely depends on what you want to do. Maybe something like a convex hull or a colored histogram of the density of lines in space. But these are just guess. You've mentioned points and lines in your problem, but since you have points and you talk about plotting lines, I'm assuming lines are important, for eg density, but I'm reading tea leaves at this point.

Comment: @tom10 1) I agree for that, I will try to implement this soon. But I still need to see vaguely how big is my complicated set composed of all the segments. I think I will just plot the convex hull. 2) The convex hull should simplify enough the plot to allow me to make an interactive plot. (I'll make sure to edit my question with all those new informations tomorow!)

Comment: @tom10 I was very busy recently but finally managed to try a lot of things. I implemented as you said but didn't work. The convex hull is plotted very fast but the projections are around the same number as the segment, even after calculating the distribution. I thing the problem comes from the way I plot (see my edit).